# AI (Adobe Illustrator) Files Detect Rasterized

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Is there a way to detect whether there are any rasterized components to an Adobe Illustrator file? Under normal circumstances such a file can be vector based (in which case it will scale well when the size is increased) but if there's a pasted image in the file, this of course won't scale. Any ideas? Any programming language implementation is welcome although in the end I would be emitting C#...

Answer (score 1):

Reference Illustrator with COM:

```
bool HasRaster = false;

Illustrator.Application app = new Illustrator.Application();
Illustrator.Document doc = app.Open("/FileName.AI", null, null);
HasRaster = (doc.RasterItems.Count > 0) ? true : false;
app.Quit();
```